# X-Win32 comparison

Tags: x-server

X-Win32 is a proprietary X Window System server for Microsoft Windows, produced by StarNet Communications : [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Win32) .
Has anyone tried this? I want to use it over a wifi network to connect to a Linux machine. Is it fast like screen refreshes etc? How does it compare to Exceed or Xming ? Anyone with experience in using this? The company gives a few like [here](http://www.starnet.com/products/xwin32/XWin32LIVEObsoletesVNC.php) and [here](http://www.starnet.com/products/xwin32/xwin_vs_exceed.php) , but i want to know a user's view when you start running apps?

Answer (score 1):

I used it about 10 years ago. If I recall, it's just an X client, so it can be sensitive to network latency and bandwidth (as compared to RDP or NX). It should be OK over wifi.

I haven't used Exceed or Xming. I have used [NX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_technology), which is very similar to Microsoft's Remote Desktop, and it's what I always recommend.

Comment: technically it provides a local Xserver that can log you into an XDMCP session on a remote server.  remember, X-servers run on the display hardware, X-clients are the programs that want to display something.

Comment: I've used NX too...much faster than VNC...but do they have a Windows server like the VNC server?

Comment: @iceman: if you're trying to display a Unix X desktop, NX does provide a Windows client to do that.  they do not provide a server for Windows like a VNC server (such that you could use it to display some Windows desktop on another client).

Answer (score 1):

I use Xming and have had no problems with it, I got it because I had some problems with the xserver cygwin provides.
But why not install Xming and try it out, it's free after all.

Earlier (5 years or so) I used X-Win32, and that also worked pretty well, can't say how it is nowadays.